# How to set the Application-Taskbar-Button of a Dialog-Based-MFC-Application

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, dialog, taskbar

I'm writing a dialog-based application with MFC. Before the main dialog shows, the application first shows a start dialog, and second a user identification dialog. Each dialog displays a application button in the taskbar. This doesn't look nice (appearing start-dialog-taskbar-button, disappearing start-dialog-taskbar-button, appearing  user-identification-taskbar-button, disappearing user-identification-taskbar-button, appearing main-dialog-taskbar-button).

How can I make only appearing one application taskbar-button from application start to application end?

Note: The dialogs are modal (`DoModal`) opened in `InitInstance`. I have also tried to open the start-dialog and user-identification-dialog within `OnInitDialog` of the main dialog, but then a taskbar-button comes only after closing the start- and user-identification-dialogs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A taskbar button is associated with a window.  Key problem it seems is that you just have too many windows.  It's a bit of a trap in MFC programming, the dialog editor is too attractive even though it is a pretty crummy UI designer.  Focus on getting *one* main window with dialogs that have their WS_EX_APPWINDOW style turned off.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`, you need to make sure that your dialogs are "owned" by the main window which has a host of other benefits thrown in. The [Windows Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx) topic on MSDN is an excellent starting point.